# smtp telnet python

Tags: python, smtp, telnet

Having some issues getting back results from telnet library but all I am getting is header and then blank waiting for input.

Any idea how can get the output from Telnet?

```
def smtp_test(server_info):
print "Check server info: " + server_info
cpos = server_info.find(':')
try:
    sock = socket()
    # sock.connect((server_info[:cpos], int(server_info[cpos+1:])))
    sock.connect(("mail.SMTPSERVERNAME.com", 25))
    print sock.recv(256)
    sock.send("HELO client.example.com\r")
    print sock.recv(256)
    sock.send("MAIL from: <sender@example.com>\r")
    print sock.recv(256)
    #sock.send("RCPT to: <recipient@example.com>")
    #print sock.recv(256)
    sock.close
    return True
except:
    return False
```

Answer (score 2):

`\r` isn't the line terminator. therefore the server doesn't reply and waits util he sees a full line, while you wait for a reply from the server. classic deadlock.

try using `\r\n`.

and you should consider using [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib) instead.

Comment: or just try `\n` at the end of the message.

Comment: @CharlesBeattie [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) specifies `<CRLF>` as line terminator. many servers accept `<LF>` alone, but they're not required to.